# Update variable in all screens of the App React Natice

Tags: react-native, variables, screen, updates

My app is both in French and English. I want the user to be able to change the language on any page and when they navigate to any other screen I want the change to be reflected.

For instance, I have A.js

```html
const A = (props) => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')
  return (
   <View style ={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress ={()=>setLanguage('french')}>{language==="french" ? changer la langue : change the language}
            </Button>
        </View>  
  )
}
```

Now when I go to any screen after pressing the button I want the content to be rendered in French and if I change the language in another screen I want `changer la langue` to be rendered in this screen

Memory leakage

```html
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('') 
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const {t} = useTranslation();    
    const fetchLanguage =  async () =>{
        try{
            const currentLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language')
            if (currentLanguage === null ){
                setVisible(true)
            }
            else{
                setLanguage (currentLanguage)
                i18n.changeLanguage(currentLanguage)
            }
        }catch (e){
            console.log(e)
        }
       
    }
    useEffect (()=>{
        fetchLanguage()
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go ahead make a context to manage that manually however that will be something like recreating wheel.

You can right away use [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) and [react-i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) to support app wide localisation with just minimal setup like below in React Native too.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
// or even better, manage them separated from your code: 
https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files)
const resources = {
  en: {
    "title": "Hello",
  },
  fr: {
    "title": "Bonjour",
  },
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    lng: 'en',  //default language.
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

Then you can easily use these translations in app via easy ways as described in the [docs](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started)

Such as

```
const {t} = useTranslations();
....
return (
  <Text>{t('title')}</Text>
)
```

**Update: Let user change the language from within the app**

You can still use this i18next to let your users change the language from within the app by just calling a simple method on i18 instance as documented [here](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide#d-let-the-user-toggle-the-language).

```
i18n.changeLanguage('fr');
```

Comment: I am not trying to detect the language from the browser of the user. I want the user to select the language the first time they access the app and they should be able change anytime they want regardless of the settings of their device

Comment: @Babou I have added that too, and the above example and libraries still make a good case even when you dont care about device settings. I hope that helps.

Comment: Check out this language chooser example: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb#language-switcher

Comment: I tried using the i18next as suggested @SurajMalviya however when I render the content just the key shows
for example 
`<Text>{t("greet")}</Text> will just render to greet.`

Comment: `const resources = {
      en: {
             "greet":"hello"
       }
     fr: {
             "greet":"Salut!!"
       }

}`

`i18n 
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        lng:'en',
        resources : resources,
        fallbackLng:'en'
        
    })`
`    const {t} = useTranslation(); `

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible code and link it here so I can see ?  I cannot read code from your above comment.

Comment: I was missing the translation @SurajMalviya Now I am able to do the translation.  However, I store the language locally and I tried reading it using a useEffect and combining that with i18n.changeLanguage(currentLanguage) causes a memory leakage. I added it to the initial post

Comment: The dependency `language` in your useEffect must be making your code go infinte, as everytime you would do `setLanguage` it would inturn call `fetchLanguage`. 

Also, could you please not use the comment section for discussion and use the discussion forum and also would appreciate if you accept the answer since it actually solved the problem.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I don't know what you meant by discussion forum and I tried removing the language from the dependencies but the issue still persists

Comment: Ah, StackOverflow had a discussion forum which can be used if a comment thread goes very long. Seems they retired it. Nevertheless, could you give a link to any github Gist with your code ? Reading code from comments is very hard man... I would really like to help you if i have a reproducible code.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue thanks a lot